# Spring Boot custom HttpMessageConverter

Tags: spring-boot

How to configure spring boot to add a custom [custom HttpMessageConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098842/how-to-make-spring-controller-to-return-csv-from-a-pojo) ?
I'm using

> AbstractHttpMessageConverter

but I don't where adding in configuration.
With Spring MVC Classic would be :

```
 <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
      <bean class="com.mypackage.TsvMessageConverter"/>
   </mvc:message-converters>
```

But Spring boot, in Application.java ?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `com.mypackage.TsvMessageConverter` is extending from `AbstractHttpMessageConverter` class, then marking it with "@Component" annotation should be enough.

From [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-responsebody-rendering):

> You can contribute additional converters by simply adding beans of that type in a Spring Boot context. If a bean you add is of a type that would have been included by default anyway (like MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter for JSON conversions) then it will replace the default value.

Comment: Btw, there is no need in: `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotations, since `@SpringBootApplication` already [contains them](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.java#L53).